# Following/tracing page construction through theme PHP

Tags: theme-development, debug

What tools and methods will allow me to figure out how a page is being constructed by WP?

I have a mix of plugins that are involved in the theme, and starting with the code I can't begin to figure out which files contain relevant code.

So, for example, I can see that a page is using a particular template, and I can open the PHP for that template, but trying to step from there to find the referenced methods and figure out when they're called in production is hopeless.

Comment: Do you mean where _looking_ at code (such as in editor) or when code is _executed_ (page actually loading in site)?

Comment: I mean following the execution path when loading a page.

Answer (score 1):

So, yes, WP can be quite a mess, more so in complicated themes. Some of it is just experience and chewing through sources.

There are, however, several things that can help to determine what is happening via code:

- Dumping [`get_included_files()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) will get you *all* PHP files loaded up to that point. It's messy, but sometimes it's what it takes.
- There are plugins like [What The File](https://wordpress.org/plugins/what-the-file/) that will give a little more now picture of template files involved.
- You can dump [`wp_debug_backtrace_summary()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_debug_backtrace_summary/) to see execution stack to a specific point in code.
- Sometimes *hooks* are more important than files, you can use helpers like [R_Debug](https://gist.github.com/Rarst/1739714) to dump live hooks execution and see what fires.